# How to split a string by colons NOT in quotes

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

I have a CSV-file delimited by colons, but it contains text-fields wrapped in quotes, which themselves contain several colons.

I would like a simple solution for getting the data fields, but eg. in ruby the split method splits on every colon.

Is there a regex which matches all colons, except those wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV parser?

Comment: +1 for using a CSV parser.  This is one of those tasks that is a lot harder than it looks and someone will have already done all the work for you.

Comment: [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) is an alternative parser that I have had good luck with.

Comment: @jleedev FasterCSV is now CSV in the standard library of Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html

Comment: This would be the perfect answer if you showed how you use CSV to change the separator to a colon.

Comment: It's a simple option, documented well.  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html#M000190

Answer (score 8):

Given:

```
str = 'foo:bar:"jim:jam":jar'
```

You can do this:

```
a = str.scan( /([^":]+)|"([^"]+)"/ ).flatten.compact
p a
#=> ["foo", "bar", "jim:jam", "jar"]
```

Or you can do this:

```
a = []
str.scan( /([^":]+)|"([^"]+)"/ ){ a << ($1 || $2) }
p a
#=> ["foo", "bar", "jim:jam", "jar"]
```

Those regex say to find *either*

- One or more characters that are not a-quote-or-a-colon, *or*
- A quote, followed by one or more characters that are not a quote, followed by a quote.

Comment: Perhaps change `"([^"]+)"` into `"((?:""|[^"])+)"` so that escaped quotes also get matched.

Comment: Magic! One problem with the above, though: consider the modified string 'foo::bar:"jim:jam":jar', with the double colon. Won't get matched.

Comment: @user613159 Then you should see @DGM's answer.

Comment: You can add another alternative to handle empty fields: `|((?<=^|:)(?=:|$))`

Answer (score 1):

you can split on double quotes instead of colons

```
>> str = 'foo:bar:"jim:jam":jar'
=> "foo:bar:\"jim:jam\":jar"
>> str.split("\"").each_with_index do |x,y|
?>  puts y%2==0 ? x.split(":") : x
>> end
foo
bar
jim:jam

jar
```

Answer (score 0):

First attempt was so bad, revised the entire thing. This is my regex solution:

GETS LAST delimeter field     `':' = :last`
Trims:   `/(?:^\s*:|:|^)\s*(".*?"|.*?)(?=\s*(?:\:|$))/`
No-trim: `/(?:(?<!^):|^)(\s*".*?"\s*|.*?)(?=\:|$)/`

## ------------------

GETS FIRST AND LAST delimeter fields    `':' = first:last`
Trims:   `/(?:^|:)\s*(".*?"|(?<!^).*?|)(?=\s*(?:\:|$))/`
No trim: `/(?:^|:)(\s*".*?"\s*|\s*(?<!^).*?|)(?=\:|$)/`

And yes, its not as easy as one thinks ..